# How to disable multiple attribute in spring select tag

Tags: spring-mvc

I have the following code:

```
<form:select path="roles" items="${roleList}" itemLabel="roleType" itemValue="id" />
```

It generates html as below:

```
<select id="roles" name="roles" multiple="multiple">
 <option value="1">ROLE_ADMIN</option>
 <option value="2">ROLE_HQ</option>
 <option value="3">ROLE_MASTER</option>
 <option value="4">ROLE_STATE</option>
 <option value="5">ROLE_CENTRE</option>
</select>
```

Also I do not use the `multiple` optional attribute. Any idea why does the generated HTML contain `"multiple="multiple"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess, but since you mapped it on `roles`, and since roles is probably a collection, it makes sense to make the select box multiple. If it was not multiple, you would only be able to store a single item in the collection. And the tag would not be able to display the selected roles.

EDIT: after reading the source code of the tag, it appears my guess was right. See the `forceMultiple()` method in `SelectTag`.

Comment: Thank you, now it makes perfect sense. In your opinion, is it better to store roles as collection or a single item ? I would like to have roles with hierarchy. For instance, a lower level role will only have rights to view but not edit.

Comment: just to complete the answer: you can add multiple="false" to disable 'multiple'-attribute even if you bind to a collection